# функция connect не видит ошибки UDP

Tags: c++, сокет, winsock

Как работает `connect` в UDP, он реагирует как то или нет?

этот код у меня не работает, он всегда пропускает ошибку, даже если сервер отключен.
Можно заставить его ждать пока не включиться сервер или хотя бы выдать ошибку соединения?

```
for (AI = AddrInfo; AI != NULL; AI = AI->ai_next) {

    // Open a socket with the correct address family for this address.

    ConnSocket = socket(AI->ai_family, AI->ai_socktype, AI->ai_protocol);

    printf("socket call with family: %d socktype: %d, protocol: %d\n",
        AI->ai_family, AI->ai_socktype, AI->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("socket call failed with %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    //**** DEBUG END

    if (ConnSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Opening socket, error %d: %s\n",
            WSAGetLastError(), PrintError(WSAGetLastError()));
        continue;
    }
    //
    // Notice that nothing in this code is specific to whether we 
    // are using UDP or TCP.
    //
    // When connect() is called on a datagram socket, it does not 
    // actually establish the connection as a stream (TCP) socket
    // would. Instead, TCP/IP establishes the remote half of the
    // (LocalIPAddress, LocalPort, RemoteIP, RemotePort) mapping.
    // This enables us to use send() and recv() on datagram sockets,
    // instead of recvfrom() and sendto().
    //

    printf("Attempting to connect to: %s\n", Server ? Server : "localhost");


    if (connect(ConnSocket, AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        break;

    i = WSAGetLastError();
    if (getnameinfo(AI->ai_addr, (int)AI->ai_addrlen, AddrName,
        sizeof(AddrName), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) != 0)
        strcpy_s(AddrName, sizeof(AddrName), UNKNOWN_NAME);
    fprintf(stderr, "connect() to %s failed with error %d: %s\n",
        AddrName, i, PrintError(i));
    closesocket(ConnSocket);
}

if (AI == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: unable to connect to the server.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: У вас сервер работает в TCP или UDP  (или он обслуживает оба протокола)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В UDP протоколе нет понятия соединения. Протокол оперирует только понятием пакета. Соответственно вызов функции `connect()` не имеет смысла.

Для отправки/приема данных по UDP протоколу используют функции `sendto()`/`recvfrom()`.

А еще в UDP протоколе нет подтверждения пакетов. Поэтому узнать обработал ли кто-то ваш пакет невозможно

Comment: А заставить хотя бы ждать соединения можно?

Comment: и без вызова connect у меня не работает код, значит он что то делает.

Comment: @grob Еще раз "соединения" нет вообще, поэтому и ждать нечего. Нужно соединение - используйте TCP

Comment: TCP глючит при соединении, там зависания происходит.

Comment: @grob тут вам выбирать - или соединение с подтверждением, либо работа в режиме радио: "я сказал, а кто меня услышал, мне все равно"

Comment: А как тогда мне отключить connect без него не работает, а раз он ничего не делает в чем его смысл?

Comment: @grob Вы внимательно прочитали весь мой ответ?

Comment: Вроде да, вы сказали что connect не имеет смыла, значит я зря его поставил, но удалить не могу, без него не работает. Что мне делать?

Comment: @grob код показывать. В моем ответе не один, а три абзаца

Comment: Обновил код, пойдет?
Как я понял это все не нужно и надо удалить, но как это удалить не знаю

Comment: @grob И что у вас не работает? Получение имени хоста?

Comment: Ну вы сказали что это не нужно, я все удаляю кроме socket и не работает.
значит надо что то еще добавить вместо connect

Comment: @grob у вас же прямо в коде комментарий про это написан

Comment: в том и дело что там какая та ерунда.

Comment: Ладно уже не важно.